# Distinct records by column value

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Let's say I have a query which its output is the given table:

```
Number    Data   Info
123    data1   info1
456    data2   info2
789    data3   info3
123    data4   info4
```

I want to get the same table with the columns,
but without records which their Number column was gotten(Not the best phrasing there,  sorry) . 
So its like a distinct.

It does not matter for me which record with the Number I keep in the result.

So the output I am looking for is:

```
 Number    Data   Info
    123    data1   info1
    456    data2   info2
    789    data3   info3
```

I am using oracle sql.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the aggregate function from MAX to others to get different values for Data and Info

```
SELECT Number, Max(Data) AS Data, Max(Info) as Info
FROM Table
GROUP BY Number
```

FIRST() might make sense for you.  Here is the oracle docs on aggregate functions:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035

Answer (score 2):

`GROUPING` would fetch you either `MAX()` or `MIN()`.. but If you want the entire row, you have to use the below Analytical Approach. Which generates a sequence for every NUMBER. When there is 2 NUMBERs of same value, it generates seq, 1 ..2

So, by selecting 1 always, you get what you. The priority of row to be chosen has to be explicitly provided.

```
SELECT NUMBER,DATA,INFO
FROM
(
   SELECT NUMBER,DATA,INFO,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  NUMBER ORDER BY <ordering column>) identifier
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
WHERE identifier = 1
```